# How to search age_from to age_to with a dob date time field in rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

New to Tire and trying to figure out how to search a DOB ( Day Of birth ) column in my Profile model.

- Try to build a simple search where I can set the age_from and age_to ( say 20 to 60 )
- How can I do this since I only have a dob field?
- Would it be better to calculate the age upon record creation and store it in a column and add that to my Profile model to clean the searching ?

What would be the best approach on this? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it with scopes, you could do:

```
scope :age_from, lambda { |age| 
 { :conditions => ["profiles.dob >= ?", DateTime.now << (12* age)] } 
}

scope :age_to, lambda { |age| 
 { :conditions => ["profiles.dob <= ?", DateTime.now << (12* age)] } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If your model has a dob field, then you can just do a query like so:

```
Profile.where(:dob => date_from..date_to)
```

You can pre-calculate `date_from` and `date_to` on the basis of whatever age you're trying to query for by doing something like `Date.today-18.years` and `Date.today-24.years`

Comment: Ended up calculating the age as a integer to a seperate field, all true the app I was calculating the age based on dob while it now calc on record save